# How to group by id first then group by a repeated field secondary?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table:

```
id                  INTEGER NULLABLE    
cost                INTEGER NULLABLE    
s                   RECORD  REPEATED    
s.amount            STRING  
s.type              STRING
```

[image]

I would like to get sum(cost) group by ID, and for every ID, get sum(s.amount) group by s.type

Example output:

```
ID, sum(cost), sum(aa), sum(bb), sum(cc)
a.  211         12      35       33
b.  123         22       0       33
c.  222         33      32.      44
```

or

```
ID,sum(cost), type, sum(amount)
a. 211        aa.   12
a. 211        bb.   35
a. 211.       cc.   33
b. 123        aa.   22
b. 123        cc.   33
c. 222        aa.   33
c. 222        bb.   32
c. 222        cc.   44
```

The output format does not matter, as long as required result can be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach(es):

For the second output:

```
select id, type, sum(cast(amount as int64)) sum_amount
from (
  select id, sum(cost) as sum_cost, array_concat_agg(s) s
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by id
) t, t.s ta
group by id, type
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

For first output:

```
select * from (
  select id, sum_cost, type, cast(amount as int64) amount
  from (
    select id, 
      sum(cost) as sum_cost,
      array_concat_agg(s) s
    from `project.dataset.table`
    group by id
  ) t, t.s ta
)
pivot (sum(amount) sum_ for type in ('aa', 'bb', 'cc'))
```

with output

[image]

Obviously above is ok when number of types is just very few and you know them in advance! If this is not a case - you can use dynamically built query as in below example

```
execute immediate (select '''
select * from (
  select id, sum_cost, type, cast(amount as int64) amount
  from (
    select id, 
      sum(cost) as sum_cost,
      array_concat_agg(s) s
    from `project.dataset.table`
    group by id
  ) t, t.s ta
)
pivot (sum(amount) sum_ for type in (''' || 
string_agg(distinct '"' || type || '"', ', ' order by '"' || type || '"') || '))'
from `project.dataset.table` t, t.s
)
```

with the same result and as you can see - you don't need to know types in advance  - above query takes care of getting all involved

Answer (score 0):

For the second format:

```
select t.id, t.cost, el.type, sum(el.amount) as total
from t cross join
     unnest(t.s) el
group by t.id, el.type, t.cost;
```

For the first, you can do:

```
select t.id, t.cost,
       (select sum(el.amount) from unnest(t.s) el where el.type = 'aa') as aa,
       (select sum(el.amount) from unnest(t.s) el where el.type = 'bb')) as bb,
       (select sum(el.amount) from unnest(t.s) el where el.type = 'cc')) as cc
from t;
```

Although this looks more complicated, it is likely to be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, first one might not work as we do not know all the types.

Comment: The second one, should `sum(sum(el.amount))` be `sum(t.cost)` ? Does not seem right though..

Comment: @vego . . . I missed that `cost` is in the parent record, not the sum of the ones in the array.

Comment: `Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed at [1:43]`
doe you mean `select t.id, sum(t.cost), el.type, sum(el.amount) as total`?

Answer (score -1):

Try This, It is tested and working. Please allocate points if it helps.

```
SELECT ID, 
sum(sum(Cost)) over (partition by ID) as Cost, 
type, 
sum(sum(amount)) over (partition by ID,type)  as amount
FROM `Schema.TABLE`
group by ID,type
order by ID,type
```

Comment: do you mean s.type?

Comment: `Cannot access field type on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, amount FLOAT64, full_name STRING, ...>> at [3:9]`

Comment: It is because of nested schema and datatype of amount field. Check my latest answer submitted in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

You have nested schema. Try below code.

```
select 
id, 
sum(sum(cost)) over (partition by ID) as cost, 
s.type, 
sum(sum(cast(s.amount as numeric))) over (partition by ID,s.type)  as amount
FROM `Schema.Table`
group by ID,s.type
order by ID,s.type;
```